# Append elements with the same class to multple divs that also share a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, code-snippets

I'm setting up a store catalog in which I have a div with multiple list items containing 2 divs (one for picture and another one for product summary and add to cart button)

Structure would be something like this.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="product">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img>
      </div>
      <div class="product-summary">
        <a class="button">Add to cart</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img>
      </div>
      <div class="product-summary">
        <a class="button">Add to cart</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

I want to move the Add To Cart button to the div that contains the image.
I tried with this jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".product-image").append(jQuery('.button'));
});
```

But this adds every sigle button to the image div, and I end up with 10+ add to cart buttons on every product. Is there any way to only move the button within each li element to its respective image div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `.each()` loop and then move the button with the same index.

```js
let buttons = $(".button");

$(".product-image").each(function(i) {
  $(this).append(buttons.eq(i));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="product">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img>Product 1
      </div>
      <div class="product-summary">
        <a class="button">Add to cart</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img>Product 2
      </div>
      <div class="product-summary">
        <a class="button">Add to cart</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```